# How malloc ask for heap memory

Tags: c, arrays, malloc

I have a huge array which I have allotted to heap, since it would lead to error if left on the stack. Now there are two methods to my knowledge which I could send this to the heap.

#1

```
int i;
int x=10000, int y=10000;
double** array=(double**)malloc(sizeof(double*)*x);
if (image) {
    for (i=0; i<x; i++) {
        array[i] =(double*)malloc(sizeof(double)*y);
    }
}
```

#2

```
double *array[x][y]=(double*)malloc(sizeof(double)*x*y);
```

Now I was wondering which method is superoir? I think #1 is asking for x blocks of legnth y in heap, which need not be next to each other. Where as #2 is asking for a block of y*x in heap. #2 is asking for a huge block of x*y, where as #1 is asking for blocks which don't need to be connected. So would #1 be superoir since it could be split up. Say the heap couldn't handle getting a huge stripe with length x*y could handle x amount of y stripes of data.

First is this even true? Am I missing something about either method? Is my argument even practical, or if true, is not a likely scenario? Got an even more superoir method?

Thanks for you insight.

Comment: the second way may fail where the first succeeds, due to fragmantation. but that's unlikely, and it is superior in any other way, AFAIK. But note that the second method does not result in a `double**` but in a `double(*)[x][y]` or something like that.

Comment: Neither. A `double**` can point to the first element of an array of `double*`. You should be using `sizeof (double*)`, not `sizeof (double)`. Better yet: `double ** array = malloc(COUNT * sizeof *array);`

Comment: @KeithThompson I guess he needs behavior and memory layout similar to `double array[x][y];`

Comment: @Elazar: Possibly -- but a `double**` isn't the way to do that. You can get similar *behavior*, but if you want contiguous layout without a second layer of pointers, things get more complicated.

Comment: @KeithThompson I will be glad to know what *is* the way. all I can think of is declaring it as a function parameter.

Comment: or `double a[20][30]; typeof(&a)`, whatever this type is.

Comment: @Elazar: That type is `double(*)[20][30]` (if you have `cdecl`, tell it `declare p as pointer to array 20 of array 30 of double`). Which typically isn't very useful, because the dimensions of the array are constant.

Answer (score 4):

You are correct that the first method *may* be more flexible because it need not find a contiguous span of free memory of the total size, whereas the second one does. A possible adverse affect of this is that this itself may cause even more fragmentation of the heap, if the slabs allocated aren't contiguous. There'll be regions of space in between each slab within which future allocations will need to find room.

The second option, however, may exploit [spatial and temporal locality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality_of_reference). Basically, since more of the data is right next to each other, there's an increased chance that the data you need will be in the CPU caches, and as a result, operating on this memory will be a lot faster.

Comment: with that matrix size (10000x10000) locality is not relevant (cpu cache lines are orders of magnitude smaller). what's important, is that you spare an extra level of indirection. also, if you access the matrix vertically, cpu can recognize this and prefetch data. this is not possible with the extra level of indirection.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath locality may be relevant when you are talking about swapping.

Comment: is there an OS which takes care for that? even if it does, it will still only make a difference with vertical access which I already mentioned...

Answer (score 1):

It dependes on the memory allocator you use and the value of your x and y.

Memory allocator often cache small memory blocks in user space and handle small allocation in user space, while forwording larger allocation request to kernel via `mmap`.

Most memory allocators work like this:

```
void* malloc(size_t size)
    if (size > THRESHOLD) {
        return large_alloc(size)     // forward to mmap
    }
retry:
    void* ret = small_alloc(size);   // handled in user space
    if (ret == NULL) {               // no small blocks left
        enlarge_heap();              // map more memory from kernel
        goto retry;
    }
    return ret;
}
```

In your case y == 10000 so you are asking for a 80000-byte memory block. In the default memory allocator in glibc, the mmap threshold is 128kB. So this request tends to be handled in user space if the allocator already cached enough memory. But #2 would invoke an mmap call since it's larger than 128kB.

But, in your example x == 10000. So you are talking about a single mmap system call call and 10000 allocations in user space. Trust me. #2 is much more faster:

An allocation in a highly optimized allocator implementation always takes more than 70 cycles on a modern x86 machine. 10000 allocations would consume more than 700000 cycles. But an typical mmap call latency should be no more than 100000 cycles. So #2 is better.

For other allocators such as TCMalloc it's a little bit different. TCMalloc  has no such threshold and always tries to handle large allocation request in user space in its `Span` structure. So #2 is definatly much better since it only need a single allocation.

---

I agree that #1 is more flexible since #2 requires the allocator to find a large contiguous memory block. But remember it is only contiguous in virtual memory, and the physical pages are mapped on-demand when you first touches it. It means it need not to be contiguous in physical memory. And it is often easy to find a 8 * 10000 * 10000 byte of contiguous memory area in virtual memory.